# How to build kernel .deb files just as in kernel-ppa/mainline?

Tags: kernel, compiling, ppa, make

I want to build just like in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.4/

I've gone to the root of the kernel source code and did:

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

just like told in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel#Building_the_kernel

*detail: I had copied the .config file from the kernel-ppa/mainline .deb file for this kernel version*

I'm getting:

```
linux-headers-4.15.4_4.15.4-4_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.15.4_4.15.4-4_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.15.4-dbg_4.15.4-4_amd64.deb
linux-libc-dev_4.15.4-4_amd64.deb
```

But according to the website, I should get:

```
linux-headers-4..._all.deb
linux-headers-4....-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
linux-image-4....-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
```

and possibly the `linux-extra...` image for newer versions.

Also here's the output of the other commands:

```
lz@air:~/Downloads/linux-4.15.4$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
make: *** No rule to make target 'binary-headers'.  Stop.
lz@air:~/Downloads/linux-4.15.4$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic binary-perarch
make: *** No rule to make target 'binary-generic'.  Stop.
```

**UPDATE:**

it's worth mentioning that my kernel is from kernel.org. What's the difference from ubuntu's kernel source? And how do I get a signed source code? I've seen only the option to clone through git.

Comment: What you are getting is what you should get. you are mixing methods a little bit. If you disable some debug stuff, your kernel compile time will be much less. The kernel.org version of the kernel does not have various Ubuntu specific patches added.

Comment: @DougSmythies thanks! By downloading ubuntu specific source code I was able to produce the desired files